# What applications does single-shot state conversion have?

Tags: quantum-operation

Many quantum processes are formulated in a resource theoretic approach like entanglement, athermality, asymmetry, coherence, etc.

Some of its topics have obvious applications, like distillation where you asymptotically convert resources to their maximal form, which is connected to the resource measure of von-Neumann entropy. However, I am not familiar with applications for single-shot (deterministic) conversion where a finite system is converted with exactness.

The center focus for single-shot conversion is which state can be converted to which state given some physical limitation. However, in quantum computing I do not see how this knowledge can be used, you apply quantum gates without having to figure out its state transformations beforehand. I also do not find catalysts to be very useful, since each transformation uses different catalysts, and you have to calculate which one to use so it does not get spent. Moreover, from an experimental perspective it is not very achievable.

So, the question is what are some applications for single-shot state conversion? (The most likely application I can think of is in one-way quantum processing.)